# 1D array passed to two functions, only one function output the correct result. Why?

Tags: c, arrays

I have two routines. I start with the array x in main. One routine is for generating triangular number for each corresponding element in array x and outputting the new array. The other routine does the same thing except it is now factorial number.

I made two calls in the main function to each routines. But only the one called first generates the correct result. So I know my code is correct for both routines. But I don't know what is wrong.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#define maxRow 3
#define maxCol 4

void factorial(int matrix[maxRow][maxCol]) {
 int row, column, i, product;
 for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
  for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {
   product = 1;
   for (i = 1; i <= matrix[row][column];++i) {
    product = product*i;
   }//innermost loop ends
   matrix[row][column] = product;
  }//inner loop ends
 }//big for ends

 printf("Factorial number matrix:\n");

 for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
  for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {
   printf("%i\t\t", matrix[row][column]);
  }//inner loop ends
  printf("\n");
 }//big for ends
}

int main() {
 void triangular(int matrix[maxRow][maxCol]);
 int x[maxRow][maxCol] = {
  { 1,2,3,4 },
  { 5,6,7,8 },
  { 9,10,11,12 }
 };//array ends
 
 factorial(x);
 triangular(x);
}


void triangular(int matrix[maxRow][maxCol]) {
 int row, column, i, sum;
 for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
  for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {
   sum = 0;
   for (i = 1; i <= matrix[row][column];++i) {
    sum += i;
   }//innermost loop ends
   matrix[row][column] = sum;
  }//inner loop ends
 }//big for ends
 printf("Triangular number matrix:\n");
 for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
  for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {
   printf("%i\t", matrix[row][column]);
  }//inner loop ends
  printf("\n");
 }//big for ends
 printf("\n");
}
```

Here is the console output:
[image]

Comment: It would be better to have `void triangular(int matrix[maxRow][maxCol]);` before `main`. Then the compiler will warn if you had a mismatch with the actual definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making changes to the `x` when called first time. Now second time when you pass it to `triangular()` , it is not the original `x` - it is the changed array `x` (The result of `factorial()` function).

Copying the array solves the problem. (make a temporary copy - print the result - then rollback the changes made to `x`).

```
void factorial(int matrix[maxRow][maxCol]) {
    int copy[maxCol][maxCol];
    int row, column, i, product;
    for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
        for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {
            product = 1;
            copy[row][column]=matrix[row][column];
            for (i = 1; i <= matrix[row][column];++i) {
                product = product*i;
            }//innermost loop ends
            matrix[row][column] = product;
        }//inner loop ends
    }//big for ends

    printf("Factorial number matrix:\n");

    for (row = 0;row < maxRow;++row) {
        for (column = 0;column < maxCol;++column) {

            printf("%i\t\t", matrix[row][column]);
            matrix[row][column]=copy[row][column];
        }//inner loop ends
        printf("\n");
    }//big for ends
}
```

In case the number increases the factorial value wouldn't hold in an `int` variable. Try using `long` to get a better range and hold larger factorial values.

Note: A pointer to the array is being passed. If we make changes to the array that the pointer points - it will change the original array.

Comment: I know when triangular is called, the matrix it receives is the new one generated by factorial. But the question is in the triangular routine, new values are assigned to each slot. Shouldn't the old factorial products be simply replaced with new triangular sums for each element?

Comment: @user132522.: The `matrix` you passed to the `triangular` function is not the original one and again you see that you are passing the `x` from `main()` again in the `triangular` function - Now you will see in this function you use the value of `matrix` and the elements on which you calculate the sum - it is the changed one. You can put a print statement - you will know. Old factorial products are replaced truly, but the values used to calculate the result is that of the factorial ones. As a result, the values you get are different from the one you would get,if you used the original initial `x`

Comment: Ok so when I am passing array x to triangular function as array matrix, array matrix simply contains a pointer to x. How do you know when an array variable contains a pointer to an existent array or to a brand new array?

Comment: If you pass an array it decays to a pointer - and you make changes to it (how do you know? You change it's value and etc). From your code it's clear that array changed. (you calculated factorial). All this is clear reading your code. If it is a new array you will either create it dynamically etc. Here you passed the original array to function. That's the way you know you are working with original array.